# JavaFX How to set Gaussian Blur in CSS

Tags: javafx

I know you can set a dropshadow in the CSS with:

```
-fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(255,255,255,0.5) , 0,0,0,1 );
```

but i wonder how do I set a gaussian blur in the CSS?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect) JavaFX only supports setting a `DropShadow` or `InnerShadow` from CSS.

> JavaFX CSS currently supports the DropShadow and InnerShadow effects from the JavaFX platform. See the class documentation in javafx.scene.effect for further details about the semantics of the various effect parameters.